# Update a json document in a mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update an existing document in a MongoDb. There are many explanations how to do this if you want to update or add key/value pairs on the first level. But in my use-case, I need to create with the first `updateOne` (with upsert option set) a document with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id" : "1234", 
  "raw" : {
    "meas" : {
      "meas1" : {
        "data" : "blabla"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the second command, I need to add - in the same document - a `"meas2"` field at the level of `"meas1"`. My desired output is:

```
{
  "_id" : "1234", 
  "raw" : {
    "meas" : {
      "meas1" : {
        "data" : "blabla"
      },
      "meas2" : {
        "data" : "foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I played with statements like

```
updateOne({"_id":"1234"},{$set:{"raw":{"meas":{"meas2":{"data":"foo"}}}}}, {"upsert":true})
```

and also with `$push`, both variants with `insert` - here only the document and also `insertOne`, but nothing produces the desired output. Is there a MongoDb expert who could give a hint ? ... I'm sure this functionality exists... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update `{$set: {"raw":{"meas":{"meas2":{"data":"foo"}}}}` you're not adding `"mesa2"` to `"meas"` but rather you're overriting `"raw"` completely.

In order to change / add one field in a document refer to it with [dot notations.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays)

The command you want is `updateOne({"_id": "1234"}, {$set: {"raw.meas.mesa2": { "data" : "foo" }}}, {"upsert":"true"})`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Please consider marking it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the below concept first

> Set Fields in Embedded Documents, with details document check at [official documentation of mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents)

For your problem, just look at the below execution on the mongo shell:

```
> db.st4.insert({
...   "_id" : "1234", 
...   "raw" : {
...     "meas" : {
...       "meas1" : {
...         "data" : "blabla"
...       }
...     }
...   }
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.st4.find()
{ "_id" : "1234", "raw" : { "meas" : { "meas1" : { "data" : "blabla" } } } }
> 
> // Below query will replace the raw document with {"meas":{"meas2":{"data":"foo"}}}, will not add 
> //db.st4.updateOne({"_id":"1234"},{$set:{"raw":{"meas":{"meas2":{"data":"foo"}}}}}, {"upsert":true})
>// By using the dot operator, you actually write the values inside the documents i.e you are replacing or adding at raw.meas.mesa2 i.e inside the document of mesa2. 
> db.st4.updateOne({"_id":"1234"},{$set: {"raw.meas.mesa2": { "data" : "foo" }}}, {"upsert":"true"})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.st4.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "raw" : {
        "meas" : {
            "meas1" : {
                "data" : "blabla"
            },
            "mesa2" : {
                "data" : "foo"
            }
        }
    }
}
>
```